# best practice for bulk update in document DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, nosql

we have a scenario where we need to populate the collection every one hour with the latest data whenever we receive the data file in blob from external sources and at the same time , we do not want to impact the live users while updating the collection.

So, we have done below

1. Created 2 databases and collection 1 in both databases
2. Created a another collection in different database( configuration database ) with property as Active and Passive and this will have the Database1 and Database2 as values for the above properties
3. Now , our web job will run every time it sees the file in blob and check this configuration database and identify which one is active or passive and process the xml file and update the collection in passive database as that is not used by the live feed and once it is done , will update the active database to current and passive to live
4. now , our service will always check which one is active and passive and fetch the data accordingly and show to user

As we have to delete the data and insert the newly data in web job , wanted to know is this is best design we have come up with ?  Does deleting and inserting the data will cost ? Is there better way to do bulks delete and insert as we are doing sequentially now

Comment: There is no "best" way - you can even create new documents in the same collection as the old documents. But if you're creating multiple databases, you have to manage multiple credentials. Multiple collections? You'd have to update your connection string simultaneously against all compute that uses that connection string (e.g. web apps, VMs, etc) and know that you're not writing to two collections at once. And yes, there's always a cost for deleting and inserting data (that's what Request Units are about - every operation costs some quantity of RU).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> wanted to know is this is best design we have come up with ?

As David Makogon said, as for your solution, you need to manage and pay for multiple databases. If possible, you could create new documents in same collection and control which document is active in your program logic.

> Does deleting and inserting the data will cost ?

the operation/request will consume the request units, which will be charged. To know Request Units and DocumentDB Pricing details, please refer to:

- [What is a Request Unit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-request-units)
- [DocumentDB pricing details](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/documentdb/)

> Is there better way to do bulks delete and insert as we are doing sequentially now

[Stored Procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-programming) that provides a way to group operations like inserts and submit them in bulk. You could create the stored procedures and then execute the stored procedure in your Webjobs function.